# How to force Visual Studio to "recognize" file differences between branches

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

The files in my TFS branch (My-DEV) are different from the parent branch (DEV). However, nothing shows up under "Pending Changes" for my workspace? How can I get Visual Studio to recognize these changes so I can merge the changes up?

I have confirmed the files are indeed different by using Compare and I am unsure of why this happened all of a sudden. Everything was working fine for the last several months. I need to essentially force an update to the parent branch.

Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition with VSO.

Comment: Yes previously, yet my changes are not in the parent branch

Comment: from the commandline: `tf merge /force /recursive`

Comment: Are you using the correct workspace?

Comment: We are assuming you are using Team Foundation Version Control repositories vs. Git repositories?